# reactjs can not combine two pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html2canvas, html2pdf, react-pdf

i'm using `@react-pdf/renderer` to download a pdf just like this :

```
const MyDocument = (props) => (
  <Document>
    <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>{props.title}</Text>   
      </View>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>Section #2</Text>
      </View>
    </Page>
    
  </Document>
);
```

and

```
<PDFDownloadLink
                document={<MyDocument title={this.state.title}/>}
                fileName="doc.pdf">
                    {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (
                        loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Download!'
                    )}
            </PDFDownloadLink>
```

i have another one page pdf which is generated using `html2canvas` :

```
printDocument() {
    const input = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
    window.scrollTo(0,0); 
    html2canvas(input)
    
      .then((canvas) => {
        
        let imgWidth = 208;
        let imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('img/png');
        const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        // pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
        pdf.save("download.pdf");
      })
    ;
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
    
      <div id="divToPrint" className="mt4">
        <div><component /></div>
      
      </div>
      <div className="mb5">
        <button onClick={this.printDocument}>Print</button>
      </div>
      
    </div>);
  }
```

i need to inject the second one inside a page of the first pdf, something like :

```
<Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <component />
        </View>
      </Page>
```

and have only one button to generate one pdf not two.
can someone help me with that and suggest a solution ?